# Android Disclosure Indicator Solution

Tags: android, lists

I developping an Android app based on its iOS twin. In one of our view, we have a list with many information but not necessarily all the information we want. In iOS, they have the right-carret disclosure indicator, but is there an equivalent in Android?

According to this page, http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html, Android app should not have any such thing. But how can I make it clear to the users that there is more info to be shown if they click on the list item?

Comment: Simply the word "more" with some indicator usually works.  You could use it as a link or a button, depending on your design.

Comment: Consider what polymer does: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-collapse?active=iron-collapse&view=demo:demo/index.html

Answer (score 4):

There are two options depending on the behavior of your app:

1. The detailed information is shown on a different screen/column of the layout: **Display no indicator**. Android users are accustomed to this and will touch a list item when they want detailed information.
2. The detailed information is shown by expanding the item and displaying the information directly beneath: **Display a carret** as shown here: https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#types (scroll to "Expand and Collapse"). You can get the icons here:

   - https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=expand_more&style=baseline
   - https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=expand_less&style=baseline

In any case, make sure that the item responds with "Material Design Ripples" when touched as shown here: https://material.io/design/interaction/states.html#pressed. This will help the user understand that the entries of your list are interactive.

Hope this helps.